# What does "An. Ox." mean?

Tags: old-english

In lexicography, what does "[An. Ox. 3778.](https://bosworthtoller.com/58832)" mean?
I found "[An.](http://lexicon.ff.cuni.cz/png/oe_bosworthtoller/a0003.png)" but I don't think that 3778 is a page.

---

<sup>This question is not asking about translations of specific texts. It is asking about linguistic terminology used in dictionaries relating to extinct languages.</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A google book search shows  "An. Ox. 3778" appears on page 717 of a 1908 Supplement to an [Anglo-Saxon dictionary](https://www.google.com/books/edition/An_Anglo_Saxon_Dictionary/pKbRAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=an.+ox.+3778&pg=PA717&printsec=frontcovershows); the front matter explains that "An. Ox." means *Anecdota Oxoniensia: Old English Glosses*, edited by Arthur S. Napier.  Napier's 1900 [work](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=nyp.33433069243487&view=1up&seq=146&skin=2021) has numbered glosses.  Number 3778 is "sub diuo, dyrnum, swellendum 52, 6 ". The meaning of "52,6"  is no doubt explained in the front matter.